# side effect of --rm: when exit a container build with docker run --rm -v /myvol, also the volume is removed

Tags: docker

I do,

```
[eric@almond volume]$ docker run  --rm --name vol -v /myvol2 -ti my/fedora-volume bash
[root@5a750a63db1d /]# exit
exit
```

With `docker volume ls` I see that the volume is gone.

Now I do without --rm,

```
[eric@almond volume]$ docker run  --name vol -v /myvol2 -ti my/fedora-volume bash
[root@5a750a63db1d /]# exit
exit
[eric@almond ch44]$ docker rm vol
vol
```

Now I see with `docker volume ls` that the volume is still there.

So has `docker run --rm` the side effect that also the volume is removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior, as documented in [the `run` reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/clean-up-rm):

> When you set the `--rm` flag, Docker also removes the volumes associated with the container when the container is removed.